# power an HDD without backpowering the PI or a powered USB hub

Tags: power, hard-drive

I have a raspberry pi being powered by a cellphone charger (1A)

I try to connect and HDD but the power is not enough. I don´t have a powered USB hub BUT i do have other power supplies. So I tried powering the HDD by myself.. but I cannot.

I tried:

I have a Y USB cable, I shortcuted the red wire from the endpoint that goes to the power suply and the HDD. So it does NOT backpower my PI. I tried 1A and 2A in the charger here. Nothing works

[image]
I also tried using the 2A adapter to power the Pi and connect the HDD to the USB thinking that 2A should be enough for everything. But it is not

I checked the specifications of the HDD and it says 5V and 1A so .... No clue why it fails.

IF I plug the HDD to my desktop PC it has no problem working. But in the Pi it starts and stops all the time making ugly noises

Any clue ??

Comment: Did you try that setup on Windows/Linux/Mac machine? Does it detect it in a nomral PC? Cutting USB cables interference issues. Try disconnecting the negative from the Pi. That could be causing loop back noise. Generally the 5Vcc and GND power the SATA controller and the spindles on the HDD and the DATA lines negotiate their own speeds, regardless of power supply. But I think you messed up your USB cable.

Comment: @ppumpkin cutting the `negative` i.e. the common ground is likely to cause more problems.

Comment: we know that for performing communication between the HDD and the PI they must share the negative. @ppumkin have you ever tried that and worked ?? BTW the HD does work flawlessly in a desktop PC

Comment: Yea the GND must be common. You right. THis is weird then.

Comment: Does it work in your desktop with the above power cabling? If it works directly, is your desktop USB 3.0?

Comment: confirm @deed02392 the cable is able to move 20Gb of files in my desktop. I connected to two USB , one is used just for data (since the red is cutted) and the juice is being sucked from the other end (the one I connect to the cellphone charger)

Comment: Could it be that the current variations are enough that it has a greater EMF effect on the Pi, interrupting communications and causing the HDD to cycle power states? Some slightly more modern drives decide to power themselves up or down based on there being an active data connection... although I see this is a drive designed for USB powering. Are you hot plugging it or connecting it and then booting up the drive? You're supposed to do the latter.

Comment: the HDD comes from an old laptop (it had only 100Gb) with a SATA to USB adaptor. I don't think that this is doing any fancy thing XD